# Microsoft Bot Framework Not Sending File Attachments

Tags: c#, botframework

I am writing a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I want the bot to respond to emails by sending attachments. I've been successful with sending images, but have been unsuccessful with sending content type for: "text/plain", "application/pdf", and "application/zip." I want to send an "application/zip" type as an attachment for the email. Here is the code I wrote:

```
private Attachment MakeBotAttachment()
{
    byte[] bytes = StorageAccess.DownloadBlobBytes();
    string contentType = "application/zip";

    return new Attachment
    {
        Name = "test-attachment.zip",
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentUrl = $"data:{contentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}"
    };
}
```

The files are being downloaded from Azure Blob Storage into a Byte Array. When I use the Bot Emulator, the message I get from the bot has a link which then opens a window saying "I'll need a new App to open this data" with a button to go to the Windows Store. When I push this code to my live service and send an email, the email has no link (like in the emulator) and no attachment.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I had a quick look to your case.
It's working on my side, I just used a file on my server, getting it as a `byte[]` (should be equivalent to your `DownloadBlobBytes`). Then doing the same steps. Tested with live email channel, working great

Comment: One idea: what is the size of the content that you want to add as attachment? there is a limit in the size of the message, be careful about that.

Comment: I've also tried reading files from my server using `File.ReadAllBytes(dataPath)` and that doesn't work (it does work for the image).  The text and zip files I tested were 1 KB each. Where does documentation indicate a file size limit for sending attachments in this way? I did test sending a large image (>1 MB) which worked in the emulator, but just threw an exception in the live service indicating `The request content length exceeded limit of 262144 bytes.`

Comment: Don't got a documentation link for that but got the same error when trying a file, then used a smaller one it was ok